# Why do Perl "split /\s+/" yield the wrong word count?

Tags: perl

Why do the perl version of these simple implementations of the unix "wc" utility produce "the wrong" answer?

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $lines=0;
my $words=0;
my $bytes=0;

while (<>) {
        $lines++;
        $bytes += length;
        #chomp;              # chomp does not make a difference
        $words += split /\s+/; # split on white spaces
}
print "$lines $words $bytes\n";
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fileinput

lines = 0
words = 0
bytes = 0

for line in fileinput.input():
    lines += 1
    bytes += len(line)
    words += len(line.strip().split()) # Python split on white spaces by default

print(f"{lines} {words} {bytes}")
```

When giving it a 20k-ish C-source file, I get the following results

```
OUTPUT:
cat source.c | ./wc.pl
19681 62506 660235

cat source.c | ./pywc.py
19681 46643 660235

cat source.c | wc
19681 46643 660235
```

So the "wc" utility agrees with python.

My suspicion is that perl's idea of white spaces are different from the rest?
(Or more likely: I am missing something with the perl split command)

```
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 60 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal input file in your question that has a different output? That way we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Perl also splits on whitespace by default.

Comment: You can use the perl script above as input. It also gives the wrong word count when compared with wc

Comment: If I remove the erroneous/\s+/ from split and allow Perl to function on same terms, it gives the same result as wc, using the perl code as input

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment of TPL basically solved the problem.

When changing `split /\s+/` to just `split`, the answer agrees with the other tools.

Turns out, as pointed out by TPL again, that `split` without any parameters will trim leading white spaces, while it won't when called with a parameter like `/\s+/`

The perldoc states:

> As another special case, "split" emulates the default behavior
> of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted
> or a string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or
> "\x20", but not e.g. "/ /"). In this case, ***any leading
> whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs***, and the
> PATTERN is instead treated as if it were "/\s+/"; in particular,
> this means that *any* contiguous whitespace (not just a single
> space character) is used as a separator.

The full solution is therefore:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $lines=0;
my $words=0;
my $bytes=0;

while (<>) {
        $lines++;
        $bytes+=length;
        $words+=split;   # split /\s+/ does not remove leading WS
}
print "$lines $words $bytes\n";
```

Comment: @pual If you check perldoc split, you will find that the default split strips leading whitespace, and the other does not. This will be significant in the case of indentation

Comment: @TLP If you put everyting in an answer, I will accept your answer and delete this one.

Comment: Your answer seems fine to me. Might include link to documentation perldoc split